# What can I do if I accidentally knock the block down multiple levels in the Fire Temple?

Tags: zelda-ocarina-of-time

I am playing the 3ds version of Ocarina of Time, and I am currently on the Fire Temple.  I reached the area where you need to use the hammer to knock down a block multiple floors, until it becomes a stepping stone leading to the locked door that needs the Boss Key.

I knocked it down one floor, and then immediately knocked it down again without checking what was in the room.  Now I can't figure out how to reach that room again, and I think it might be necessary to go through that room in order to get to the Boss Key.  Is there any way I can reach it?

I can't just shut off my 2ds; I accidentally saved after I messed up.

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking of the wrong room: I'd already been to the invisible fire wall maze, where I needed to go to and press a rusty switch with the hammer.